# Moving or closing cold air return

Tags: heating, vent, subfloor

Here is my current situation:

[image]

There used to be a wall running between two rooms here; with a heat vent on the top side room and what looks like two cold air returns on the other. The issue is, with the wall gone, these have just been in the middle of the room next to each other for years.

The heat vent on the left has been moved closer to the wall, on the right. This was fairly straightforward.

My question now is, what should I do with the returns?

Would very bad things happen if I close them off? (This is one of 2 other returns upstairs, the closest one being about 15' away in the hallway).

Part of the "rightside" return extends into the joist cavity where I've moved the heat. I could open that up and have it pull air from that cavity, though the hole would be about 1/4 the size of the current one; so much less airflow back to the furnace, but still better than nothing. Though it'd be about 1'-2' away from the heat on the floor, so not sure if that'll be an issue as well.

---

**Update:**

Been doing some more reading and I'm going to look into moving those returns to the opposite wall.

If I move it beside the supply register then the hot air that comes out will just move a few feet back into the intake and at that point I may as well just close them both off since it won't be doing much to distribute heat or circulate the air.

If I close the returns then there may be an issue with the balance of air leaving vs entering the furnace, circulation in that room, and the furnace pulling air from random crevices.